# cmd works but C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe does not

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I am trying to invoke one executable by putting following line on command prompt. (I know I can directly invoke the exe but let's just say I have no other way to do this due to some restriction)

```
"cmd /C" "C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc"
```

itself It is successfully run. `/C` is parameter to `cmd.exe`. But when I do this

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C" "C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc"
```

Gives me error

```
The directory name is invalid
```

Any idea why? And how can I solve this problem? I have to use full path of cmd.exe.

Comment: The odd part is that the first format works ... I can reproduce the behaviour but I can't explain it!  It doesn't work with executables other than `cmd`, so it looks as if it may be a hard-coded special case. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange it seems :/

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C " "C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc" "
```

This works. Don't know why.  May be the double quotes before and after `"C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc"` are required. Wish if someone will explain that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C " "C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc" "
```

For example:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C " echo "Hello World" "
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C " python -c " print 'Hello World' "
```

These work without any problem and both of them output "Hello World"

Comment: +1 or avoiding hard coded paths; `"%COMSPEC%" /C "C:\Prog ..."`

Comment: @GaneshS OK, now I get what you were trying to do. You should have been much more clear about your question. But, there you go, the edited answer :D

Comment: Any idea why this works? As per my interpretation " "abc" "xyz" " should be intrepreted as  wrong format not as nested double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Stephan, the correct way of writing it is some of the following options

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C ....
"%comspec%" /c ....
```

The question is `Why "cmd /c" .... works?` It works for the way the parser is interpreting the line.

When the line is readed and parsed, `"cmd /c"` is converted to

```
execute the command interpreter with the /c" ... arguments
```

So it is executed as

```
%comspec% /c ".....
```

This substitution can be easily tested

```
set "ComSpec=c:\windows\system32\calc.exe"
"cmd /c" echo hello
```

Comment: so `cmd` is different to (for example) `notepad`. `notepad` searches in the path for a file `notepad.xxx`, where `xxx` is `bat`,`cmd` or `exe` (something, that is in `%pathext%`), while `cmd`is not searching for `cmd.exe` but seems to be a sort of "internal command", which executes `%comspec%`, maybe like a `doskey`macro?

Comment: @Stephan, yes, it is different. I don't know if it is related, but `start` command does something similar. From its help `When you run a command that contains a the string "CMD" as the first token without an extension or path qualifier, "CMD" is replaced with the value of the COMSPEC variable. This prevents users from picking up cmd from the current directory.`

Comment: It appears that the initial quote mark is discarded as a (presumably unintentional) side-effect of the conversion of `cmd` to `%ComSpec%`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C"
```

looks for a file named `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C`.

Have you ever seen a file with the extension `.exe /c`?

Correct format is:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C
```

Comment: If that the case, any idea
"cmd /C" "C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc" why this works??

Comment: `"cmd /c"` and `"cmd.exe"` works, `"cmd.exe /c"` doesn't. Seems to use different parsers. Let's wait for one of our experts to answer...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the additional question of why the extra quotes are needed: this is described in the help returned by `cmd /?`, specifically

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
>   the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
>   used to process quote (") characters:
>
> ```
> 1.  [Special case, not relevant here]
>
> 2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>     a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>     remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>     any text after the last quote character.
> ```

So, if the first (non-whitespace) character of the command is a quote, you need an extra pair of quotes around the entire command.

---

Additional note: combining MC ND's answer with mine, the first command line in the question is being interpreted like this: we start with

```
"cmd /C" "C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc"
```

which becomes

```
%ComSpec% /C" "C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc"
```

due to the rule that replaces `cmd` -> `%ComSpec%` combined with the bug/feature that discards the extra quote mark; this then becomes

```
"C:\\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe" -register="abc
```

because of the rule that removes the first and last quote marks when processing `/C`.

The Win32 file system rules discard the extra backslash, so the executable launched is

```
C:\Program Files\ABC\xyz.exe
```

and the executable is presumably ignoring the missing close-quote in its argument.

Comment: Great help here. Thank you very much. :)